# how to convert base 2 floating point number to base 10?

Tags: floating-point

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLmGm.png)

How can we convert $(1.11)_2$ * 2 to $(3.5)_10$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1.11` in base 2 is `1+1/2+1/4=1.75`, and so `1.75*2=3.5`.